# Why can't my ExtendScript access the `name` property for some fonts returned to me by `app.activeDocument.fonts`?

Tags: fonts, adobe, extendscript, adobe-indesign

I'm making an ExtendScript script which goes through all the fonts used in an InDesign document and alerts their name. Here is the code

```
var usedFonts = app.activeDocument.fonts;
var nbUsedFonts = usedFonts.length;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < nbUsedFonts; ++i) {
  alert(usedFonts.item(i).name);
}
```

For certain fonts however, the script crashes (Object is invalid) when I access their `name` property. The only attribute I can access for all fonts without crashing is the `isValid` attribute, which allowed me to determine that those fonts for which I couldn't access the `name` property all had `isValid === false`, whereas all fonts for which accesing `name` didn't cause a problem had `isValid === true`.

What surprises me is that if I manually place my cursor in the text where one of the problematic fonts is used, its name appears the the normal *font chooser* or whatever it's called.

Why can't I access the `name` property for some fonts returned to me by `app.activeDocument.fonts`?

**Note:**

Here are some of the problematic fonts:

- Electra LH, Italic
- Electra LH, Bold Small Caps & Oldstyle Figures
- Electra LH, Oldstyle Figures
- Ocean Sans MT, Light OsF

These fonts work without problem:

- Ocean Sans MT, Light Italic OsF
- Ocean Sans MT, Semibold SC
- Ocean Sans MT, Light SC
- Ocean Sans MT, Light
- Electra LH, Small Caps & Oldstyle Figures
- Electra LH, Cursive
- Electra LH, Bold Oldstyle Figures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may come from fonts missing, you may try to check for these first, and see if it solves your problem:

```
var usedFonts = document.fonts;
for(var i = 0; i < usedFonts.length; i++){

    if(usedFonts[i].status != FontStatus.INSTALLED){
        //You can't rely on font.name if the font is missing
        var fontName = usedFonts[i].fontFamily+" "+usedFonts[i].fontStyleName;
    }else{
        var fontName = usedFonts[i].name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using `fontFamily` and `fontStyleName` for every font.